# MYSQL: Query the last conversion on chat messages and sort by latest message

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, sorting

I am having issue on query sorting of last convo messages of each users.
Here is my current record on my 2 tables:

[image]

[image]

I want to achieve below result:

[image]

My current query is:

```
 SELECT `messages`.*, `users`.`username`, `u2`.`username` as `to_username`,
 CASE WHEN to_user_id = 1
    THEN `users`.`username`
    ELSE u2.username
 END as participant
 FROM `messages` 
 LEFT JOIN `users` ON `messages`.`from_user_id`=`users`.`id` 
 LEFT JOIN `users` as `u2` ON `messages`.`to_user_id`=`u2`.`id` 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as lastmsgId FROM messages where to_user_id = 1 or from_user_id =1 GROUP BY to_user_id) m2 ON `messages`.`id`=`m2`.`lastmsgId` 
 GROUP BY participant  
 ORDER BY `messages`.`created_at` DESC
```

And the result of my query is:
[image]

The 4th and 5th message is not sorted properly I am expecting to display the 4th message
instead of 5th message. It displays the older message instead of latest one. I couldn't find the solution on how will be display the right sorting.

Any help and suggestion is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is no self-messages:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM messages t1
JOIN ( SELECT LEAST(from_user_id, to_user_id) user1,
              GREATEST(from_user_id, to_user_id) user2,
              MAX(created_at) created_at 
       FROM messages t2
       GROUP BY user1, user2 ) t3  ON t1.from_user_id IN (t3.user1, t3.user2)
                                  AND tm1.to_user_id IN (t3.user1, t3.user2)
                                  AND t1.created_at = t3.created_at ;
```

Join `users` table if needed.

If `id (1) < id (2)` => `created_at (1) < created_at (2)` then you may replace all occurences of `created_at` with `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about performance in mysql, but:
I assume id can be used as order by as well if its identity, but:

Sorry, no formating, on mobile.

Select max(id) from messages group by least(from_user_id, to_user_id), greatest(from_user_id, to_user_id)

On that you can join based on id to get rest of columns